# Blank lines appearing in a CSV exported from Excel, only on 1 Mac, other Macs don't see them

Tags: macos, ms-office, text-editor

My colleague and I both use Macbook Pros on the latest Mac OS.

He exports CSV files from MS Excel for Mac and sends them to me, but when I receive them I open them in a text editor and there are blank lines on every other line.

Weirdly though, **when he opens the same file on his machine in the same text editor, he does not see blank lines**. Which makes me wonder if this is a setting on his machine.

I know Windows and Mac treat line endings differently, but we are both on a Mac. And Sublime should be the same on both machines.

When I upload them to our linux server, linux agrees with me (our scripts see blank lines in the CSVs and have to be ignored).

He is creating CSVs using the UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your file with `od -cx` you will notice that every lines is terminated by the sequence: `0x0d 0x0a` i.e. a carriage return followed by a newline.

There is most probably a difference between your 2 `Sublime Text` preferences in their way to manage the carriage return.

The next best explanation is a difference in extension you gave on your 2 text files which set `Sublime Text` in a different way to manage the character `carriage return` == `0x0d` (coming from the last century type writers).